# Sql: Casting INT to string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
TableA

OFIPS int null,
DFIPS int null
```

Query below returns a record.

```
SELECT OFIPS from TableA Where OFIPS = 01077
```

But this query doesn't.

```
SELECT OFIPS from TableA Where CAST(OFIPS as nvarchar(5)) = '01077'
```

Not sure what the problem is. Please help.

Comment: What is the need for the above where condition where in you are casting the int values having leading zeroes to varchar?

Comment: Also whether your first query 'Where OFIPS = 01077' returns OFIPS as '01077' or '1077'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in `int` column leading zero's will be ignored, `01077` will be stored as `1077` and when you query like

```
Where OFIPS = 01077
```

It will be parsed as

```
Where OFIPS = 1077
```

There will be a record stored as `1077` so you are getting result.

But when you query like

```
Where CAST(OFIPS as nvarchar(5)) = '01077'
```

It checks for the records with `01077` thats why you are not getting result in second query

---

Interestingly if you remove the `CAST` in `Where` clause again it will work. Even though you query with leading zero in string format.

```
Where OFIPS = '01077'
```

Because LHS `OFIPS` has `INT` datatype which has higher precedense than the RHS `Varchar`. Implicitly string in the RHS(`01077`) will be converted to int `1077`

Answer (score 1):

**Implicit Conversion**

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql

Meaning, that '01234' = 1234 will result to TRUE, since '01234' will be converted to INT. INT has a higher precdence.

**Explicit conversion**

Converting `INT` to `VARCHAR` - like `CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), 1234)` - will not add leading zeros therefore `'01234'` not equals to `CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), 1234)`.

You can forcibly add the leading zeros if you have a fixed length: `RIGHT(CONCAT('00000', CONVERT(CHAR(5), 1234)), 5)`

**Remarks**

Consider to keep the `INT-INT` comparison, force convert the input values to INT instead of converting the column values.

If the above is not possible, consider to store the values in the database as fixed length character values (`CHAR(5)`) and make sure, that the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements are transforming the values to their desired format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this because OFIPS of type is int. Int type is not '01077'. I hope that it help you.

```
SELECT OFIPS from TableA Where CAST(OFIPS as nvarchar(5)) = '1077'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column is `int` and the only int that can have a leading 0 is 0.
Other numbers have no leading 0 because they are not strings but numbers.

When you search for `Where OFIPS = 01077` 01077 is implicitly converted to 1077,
and this number exists in your table.
When you do `CAST(OFIPS as nvarchar(5))` no leading 0 can appear so no one number will be casted to '01077'